# Multiple get_posts() queries on one page

Tags: loop, page-template, get-posts

I'm building custom page template, which has some content editable through proper articles/posts. Below are those code blocks:

```
<?php
$contact = new WP_Query();
$contact = get_posts( array( 'slug' => 'contact-home' ) );
if ( $contact )
{
echo apply_filters ("the_content", $contact[0]->post_content);
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

.. some template code ...

<?php
$about = new WP_Query();
$about = get_posts( array( 'slug' => 'about-home' ) );
if ( $about )
{
echo apply_filters ("the_content", $about[0]->post_content);
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

.. some template code ...

<?php
$history = new WP_Query();
$history = get_posts( array( 'slug' => 'history-home' ) );
if ( $history )
{
echo apply_filters ("the_content", $history[0]->post_content);
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

But whatever I do, all variables always have array with variables prepended from other queries (so e.g. `$about[0]` gives me query result from `$history`, `$about[1]` gives `$about` results, and `$about[2]` returns `$contact` results).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think I'm right in saying that you don't need to use `wp_reset_postdata()` unless you are planning to expand your code to make use of `setup_postdata()`.

Comment: Also, if you are using `get_posts()` you can get rid of the `$var = new WP_Query()` line above each call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slug` is not a valid query paramter, so `get_posts()` will just return X latest posts!

Use `name` instead.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters